# How do I port a filetype command to neovim's lua format?

Tags: neovim, filetype, lua

Currently my `.vimrc` file has this in it,

```
filetype plugin indent on -- filetype detection[ON] plugin[ON] indent[ON]
```

How can I port `filetype plugin indent on` to neovim's lua format?

Comment: Why? Just use the Vim Script

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt because I _need_ to do something with Lua, so I _want_ to do everything in Lua. And also, I think Vim Script sucks pretty bad (my opinion).

Comment: Sorry, but if I look at your other question and answer, I believe lua is pretty unreadable and too verbose.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt that's fine. Different strokes for different folks. You do you. I'll do me. Hopefully the contributions will help the larger vim community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I port `filetype plugin indent on`?

You don't. This is the default (in Neovim).

From `:he nvim-defaults`,

> - Syntax highlighting is enabled by default
> - `:filetype plugin indent on` is enabled by default

Comment: how can I validate that?

Comment: @EvanCaroll The same way you validate it works at all. Or learn to read what silent help hath writ.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer, but if you're not going to tell me where I can find the defaults listed for `filetype` (I don't see them in `:he filetype`) then I'm afraid I won't be accepting it.

Comment: Follow up question https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37197/5078

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`vim.api.nvim_command()`](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#vimapinvim_command), which allows you to run an Ex command from Lua.

```
vim.api.nvim_command('filetype plugin indent on')
```

It's also possible to use [`vim.cmd()`](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#vimcmd), which is actually an alias for `vim.api.nvim_exec()`, but that's similar enough to `vim.api.nvim_command()` and also works well in this case.

```
vim.cmd('filetype plugin indent on')
```

---

You seem to imply that you expect there should be a native way to run this command (and to some extent *every* Ex command) directly in Lua. But that's really not the case.

See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37193/18609) for further discussion on the point of Lua and whether Ex commands and Vimscript are meant to be completely avoided and deprecated in favor of Lua in NeoVim.

Comment: I think you hit on a strong misunderstanding I had, but I also don't feel it should be on this question. Can we explore that a bit more  -- I split that off because I'm not the only one doing this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37193/5078 I have one more follow up too I would like to ask about generally how Lua fits into the neovim stack. Thanks for trying to point me in the right direction. Not in that question, but in the _next_ follow up that I have not asked, I'll actually tell you _why_ I was led down this direction and ask for specific guidance on it.

Comment: Good point! I split the part relevant to that discussion into that question. Hopefully we'll also get more answers perhaps citing official NeoVim docs or what the authors said (they often talk in conferences and events) regarding that specific point too!