# Is the goal of Lua in neovim to replace Ex, and if not what is it?

Tags: neovim, ex-mode, lua

I am a new user to neovim, and [a moderator on this site said](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37186/5078)

> You seem to imply that you expect there should be a native way to run [`filetype`] (and to some extent every Ex command) directly in Lua. But that's really not the case.

That's a fair point. I did assume and expect the Lua API to provide full support for everything you could do in Ex. If that not the case, should a lack of functionality in Lua be looked at is a part of the design, or merely things that yet need to be done. Is there a document on Lua in VIM and the design goals or a post on the mailing list detailing this?

Answer (score 4):

The point of Lua support in NeoVim is not really to replace Ex commands altogether. That wouldn't really be possible (consider commands like `:e` or `:w` or `:s` etc.) or productive. Instead, the point of Lua in NeoVim is to replace Ex commands (and Vimscript to some extent) as the only or main language in which to write *plug-ins* for NeoVim.

So while rewriting Vimscript plug-ins in Lua makes a lot of sense (and is likely to produce performance and usability gains), there's not really a lot of value in rewriting your configuration in Lua. Even if you do, you're likely to end up using quite a few Ex commands in that, so use of `vim.cmd()` and friends is the way to go there.

Comment: I would love to know _why_ there isn't a `nvim_write_buf(handle)` api call in Lua. If by design, that seems weird. There is an `nvim_list_bufs()`