# Recommended way to run vimscript normal commands with lua

Tags: neovim, normal-mode, vimscript-lua

What is the *recommended* way to run VimScript normal commands in Neovim with Lua?

Sometimes, I can achieve things very easily with a few *keypresses* executed as a `normal` command compared to scripting the whole thing with Lua API.

Now I know I can use `vim.cmd` and just put the whole `normal ...` command inside there, but I was wondering if there was any overhead to this and if yes what is then the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that Lua API is to be an alternative to VimScript API (function calls) but not to replace Vim commands.

Vim commands are and will be available from Lua using the `vim.cmd` call among others.

The overhead is minimal (the parsing of the Vim command). But if the action is complex, the Vim command is in general more performant than its simulation using the VimScript API or its Lua variant (C code is likely to be more performant than script code).

My recommendation is to use Vim command whenever possible unless it can be replaced by one API call (VimScipt API or ots Lua variant)

Keep VimScipt or its Lua variant for what can't be done with Vim commands.

Here another [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37194/23502) from an expert sharing its opinion.

Comment: Good answer but source?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do a bit better than `vim.cmd('normal w')` using:

```
 vim.cmd.normal('w')
```

Unfortunately, keycode are not expanded. You have to combine it with  `nvim_replace_termcodes()`:

```
vim.cmd.normal(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<Up>', true, true, true))
```

Note that [`vim.keymap.set()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.keymap.set()) automatically expand keycodes, so if your idea was to set your keybind using lua, it is still far shorter to use vimscript.