# How to convert plugin specific vimrc configurations into lua?

Tags: neovim

I have a full lua config on my Neovim setup.
It seems we can't have both `init.vim` and `init.lua` on the same setup.

I am trying to setup [fugitive-gitlab.vim](https://github.com/shumphrey/fugitive-gitlab.vim), but it provides vimscript instructions.
Both fugitive-gitlab and fugitive are successfully installed via Lazy.nvim.

When configuring as per the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/shumphrey/fugitive-gitlab.vim#installation):

```
let g:fugitive_gitlab_domains = {'ssh://my-ssh.gitlab.com': 'https://my.gitlab.com'}
```

I tried to translate that to the following lua function:

```lua
function ConfigGitlab()
    vim.g.fugitive_gitlab_domains['ssh://git@gitlab.company.com:121112'] = 'https://gitlab.company.com:3344'
end
```

But when I call this, I get:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/v4g4x/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /Users/v4g4x/.config/nvim/lua/core/gitlab.lua:3: attempt to index field 'fugitive_gitlab_domains' (a nil value)
```

Clearly, I'm not converting from Vimscript to Lua correctly.
Any help on how this may be done?

Comment: The answers to [Recommended way to run vimscript normal commands with lua](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42029/recommended-way-to-run-vimscript-normal-commands-with-lua) may help.

Comment: BTW, accessing a key in an uninitialized dictionary would result in an error in vimscript as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to convert `init.vim` into `init.lua` the [nvim-lua-guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide/) helps or directly from the Neovim documentation [Lua-guide](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html#lua-guide) page.

But of course some knowledge of Lua too :-)

I would do:

```lua
vim.g.fugitive_gitlab_domains = { ['ssh://git@gitlab.company.com:121112'] = 'https://gitlab.company.com:3344'
```

Remark: In general a dictionary in Lua is defined like:

```lua
mydict = { mykey1 = myvalue1, mykey2 = myvalue2}
```

e.g.

```lua
name2age = { foo = 42, bar = 84 }
```

But when the keys are not identifiers you have to rely on the following syntax:

```lua
mydict = { ['my key 1'] = myvalue2, ['my key 2'] = myvalue2}
```

Comment: Yup, this worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback!