# Where does neovim store its defaults? Where is the defaults.vim for neovim?

Tags: neovim, default-settings

On regular vim, you can find the defaults in [`defaults.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/defaults.vim). These are sourced when there is no `.vimrc`, or when you include in your `.vimrc` the following,

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim " Source the defaults
```

Where does Neovim **specify** the defaults? Where in the code? I can see them documented in `:help nvim-defaults`, but I am wanting to know where they're **implemented.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaults are stored in [`src/nvim/options.lua`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/src/nvim/options.lua)

Which is part of the neovim source code.

Answer (score 4):

`$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` is NOT the defaults. It is a script that changes them. It could be sourced under some circumstances but it is still only an optional script. No one is required to use it. Neovim does not provide anything like that.

Now to the question. Global options are created on startup. They are initialized internally with values stored directly in source code (except a few being evaluated). But every option is documented and default values are part of such documentation.

However it does not matter that much. Vim is not "an editor plus config data", it is "a virtual machine" that consists of data and code. Hence all customizations are done by scripting.

So real questions are

- what options exist and what do they do?
- what is the current value? when and why it was changed?
- what commands were already been executed? in what order?
- what commands will get auto-executed later? under which condition?

And short answer is

- run `nvim-qt -- -u NONE`
- (optional) type `:colorscheme XXX<Enter>` and `:set guifont=YYY<Enter>`
- press F1
- start reading

Comment: The question doesn't call for documentation. It actually references the explicit places `nvim-defaults` that documents the defaults, so it seems far from being useful a answer. Just referencing `F1` is just a snide response akin to RTFM. It would have been far more useful to show where the defaults for an option were in the source, like say the `filetype` option. I went looking. I didn't see it.